# define if two planes are parallel

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

I am trying to develop a function to determine if 2 planes are parallel or not.

I have their equations :

```
P1 : a1.x + b1.y + c1.z + d1 = 0
P2 : a2.x + b2.y + c2.z + d1 = 0
```

I check :

```
a1=0 & a2=0 => parallel
b1=0 & b2=0 => parallel
c1=0 & c2=0 => parallel

else, if a1/a2 = b1/b2 = c1/c2 => parallel
```

I have some big doubts about it, because I read on courses that none of parameters may be equal to 0, but if I have a plane on $(x,y)$, with $z=10$, the equation may be :

$z-10 = 0$, so $a, b =0$, right?

How could I check parallelism, taking in account each particular case?

After thinking, I guess it may be something like that :

```
(a1=0 & a2=0) => no need to check equality
(b1=0 & b2=0) => no need to check equality
(c1=0 & c2=0) => no need to check equality

if (a1=0 & a2!=0) or (a1!=0 & a2=0) => not parallel
if (b1=0 & b2!=0) or (b1!=0 & b2=0) => not parallel
if (c1=0 & c2!=0) or (c1!=0 & c2=0) => not parallel
```

Where `!=` means different

Then check if `a1/a2 = b1/b2 = c1/c2` (if I need to check)

Aside : How can I insert here some mathematical signs, I cannot find?

Comment: To avoid worrying about zero, you could check whether $(a1.b2=a2.b1) and (a1.c2=a2.c1) and (b1.c2=b2.c1)$

Comment: In fact, I just found a better course, that is giving the definition. In fact, I can have 1a=0, or b1=0, or c1=0, but never 3 of thm = 0, right?

Comment: Yes, check for that too

Comment: You should check mathjax - where we write math within `$...$` for typing out math signs.
Math Meta Stackexchange has a mathjax tutorial, search for it

Comment: @Empty thanks that helped. if you write as answer, I could accept it, or may I accept `jp bouchon`'s answer, as it is good explained too, don't know what may be the correct way.

Comment: @Siegfried.V Empy2's comment and jp bouchon's answer give the same condition.

Comment: Your test suggest that the planes $x=1$ and $y=2$ are parallel

Comment: @Apass.Jack that's why I askd. Empy answerd first. Never mind I accepted it. And Hagen von Eitzen I know, that's why I asked, I saw something was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a plane $P$ has $ax+by+cz+d=0$ as cartesian equation —with $(a,b,c)\ne(0,0,0)$—, then the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
a\\ b\\ c
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
is orthogonal to $P$.

Now two planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ are parallel **iff** $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
a_1\\ b_1\\ c_1
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
and
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
a_2\\ b_2\\ c_2
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$
are “proportional”, i.e., linearly dependent, which is in turn equivalent to
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1&a_2\\
b_1&b_2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1&a_2\\
c_1&c_2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
b_1&b_2\\
c_1&c_2
\end{vmatrix}=0.$$
That is: $a_1b_2-a_2b_1
=a_1c_2-a_2c_1
=b_1c_2-b_2c_1=0$.

Comment: you wrote `with (a,b,c)≠(0,0,0)`. Could you explain why? As I understood, a,b,c are not necessarly ≠ 0 ?

Comment: This is because the cartesian equation $0.x + 0.y + 0.z + d=0$ doesn't define a plane. According to the value of $d$, this equation defines $\emptyset$ (for $d≠0$) or $\Bbb{R}^3$ (for $d=0$). To define a plane _at least one of the coefficients_ must be ${}\neq0$. Put otherwise: the affine plane P has for _direction_ a vector space $\vec P$, which is defined as the kernel of a non-zero linear form $\ell$, and $P$ has $\ell(x,y,z)+d=0$ for equation (for some $d\in\Bbb{R}$. Such a linear form is of the type $\ell(u,v,w)=au+bv+cw$ for some $(a,b,c)\neq(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood the comment. I believed none of them may be equal to 0. Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot :).